# How can I stream PC Games to a Roku Box in real-time?

Tags: pc, streaming

I would like to stream my PC games from my computer to my Roku 3. I can use my wireless Xbox 360 controller to play. Is this even possible, and if so how can I do it?

Comment: Maybe you can stream your screen from something like VLC to Plex on the Roku but it will not be real time. Roku is designed around steaming/buffering which is a terrible mix for video game display.

Comment: Just run a cable to your tv.  Works great for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not in realtime. A streaming networked device like the Roku will always introduce a large delay, at least in the high hundreds of milliseconds, but probably multiple seconds. Your screen and audio would feel very out of sync.

To get a realtime audio signal, you have to have a very fast connection. With today's networking technology, that means that a networked device is out of the question and you need something that connects without using networking protocols. A direct audio cable, or a wireless (non-networking) audio system would be needed to get the speeds necessary to avoid audible lag.

Comment: thanks i am wired but is it even possible

Comment: @user1495129 No, sorry. Even a wired *network* connection would introduce major sound lag. Networking protocols just aren't designed for realtime data transmission. You need a direct analog audio cable to carry sound data without losing sync.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, so how do you explain the awesome playability of games when streamed over network via Steam In-Home streaming (computer to computer) or from computer to Nvidia's handheld Shield device?

Comment: @JonL. Haven't used 'em, but I imagine they use the old concept of moving *execution* over the stream instead of the sound/video/input. We had that capability in the 80s. Or, they've solved some sync problems with clever engineering. Regardless, the Roku's protocol is not designed to solve sync problems, and in fact exploits the lack of need to sync in order to add quality buffering.

Comment: Other streaming devices can do this just fine (with similar [and/or worse] hardware than the Roku), and it works great. -- It seems the Roku should be able to do this with the right software, no problem. -- If it can't, it's just a lack of software. -- Just look at limelight.

Comment: Four years on, yeah, I think this answer is out of date with improvements in streaming technology. But I'm still pretty sure the **Roku 3** specifically still can't.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that, Steam has it's own proprietary network link (The [Steam Link](http://store.steampowered.com/universe/link/)) and also a nifty controller. Users seem to give positive reviews.